# Retesting while loop condition inside a nested while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

in this program I don't really understand why we test condition 1 of the first while loop in the nested while loop

The program is made to say how many words are in a string, words are separated by spaces

Here's the code:

```
int count_words(char *ch){
    int c = 0;
    while(*ch!='\0'){
        if(*ch==' '){
            ch++;
            continue;
        }
        c++;
        while(*ch && *ch !=' '){
            ch++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

What I do not understand is why condition 1 which is : (*ch!='\0') in the first while loop is tested again in the second while loop.

Do I always have to test back conditions in nested while loops ? Or is there is there something I didn't grasp properly ?

Thanks

Comment: Nesting is not the issue; when `ch` is advanced, then the one has to test it again. The inner loop does _one_ extra test that's not necessary because `ch` has already been tested against `'\0'` and `' '` in _the first loop_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I do not understand is why condition 1 which is : (*ch!='\0') in the first while loop is tested again in the second while loop.

I'll focus on some important details here:

```
while(*ch!='\0') {
    if(*ch==' ') {
        ch++;                  // 1.
        continue;
    }
    c++;
    while(*ch && *ch !=' ') {
        ch++;                  // 2.
    }
}
```

In both `1` and `2`, the `char*` `ch` increases by one, which makes `ch` point at a new address - with unknown content.

When the start of the `while` loop is reached again, it tests if what `ch` is pointing at contains the *null-terminator* which signifies the end of the string. If it does, the loop ends - because the string is then fully examined.

So, `while(*ch!='\0')` is not testing the same thing over and over again. `ch` points at a new `char` after every loop.

You have the same test in the inner loop:

```
    while(*ch && *ch !=' '){    // <-here
        ch++;
    }
```

Here, `*ch` is doing the same test, `*ch != '\0'`, but in not so many words.

- `\0` is the proper character literal for the null-terminator.
- The null-terminator has the actual value `0`.
- In boolean context, `0` evaluates to `false` and anything else evaluates to `true`.
- Hence, `*ch`  equals  `*ch != '\0'` in boolean contexts

Comment: I thought '\0' is literally `(char)0`; am I wrong?

Comment: @Neil For all practical reasons, it is. It may even be mandated by the standard. Using `*ch` instead of testing literally is so common that I think the world would end if it wasn't true everywhere.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate the help I didn't understand at first why we tested *ch in both loops. But it's cristal clear now

Comment: @FangYuan You're welcome! Glad it helped!

Comment: @TedLyngmo ISO9899 5.2.1 "A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string." I understand it to mean a null-terminator has the value `'\0' == 0`, in all systems. (Unlike 0 in pointer contexts.)

Comment: @Neil Brilliant! Then it _is_ safe to make that assumption. Good. I've got tons of code depending in on that :-) I edited my answer to not be so wobbly on that matter.

Answer (score 3):

The first test is for skipping over all the spaces between words. It stops when it gets to the first non-space, i.e. the *beginning* of a word.

The inner while loop is for skipping characters until we get to the next space, so it finds the *end* of that word.

Notice that the two conditions are opposite. The first one is `*ch == ' '`, the second one is `*ch != ' '`.

`*ch != '\0'` and `*ch &&` are used to stop when we get to the end of the string (C strings end with a zero byte). That's needed in any loop that steps through the string so it doesn't go beyond the end.

Comment: I think the first test in the inner loop is redundant; it could have been a do-while.

Answer (score 2):

This question demonstrates why, in my opinion, breaking things out into functions that can have meaningful names is so important.

Let's say we want to advance a string past leading whitespace characters. We can create a function that takes a string (`char *`), creates a pointer to point to the start of it, increments that pointer until it hits a character that is not a space, tab, or newline, then returns that pointer.

```c
char * first_nonspace(char * s) {
    char * iter = s;

    for (; *iter && (*iter == ' ' || *iter == '\t' || *iter == '\n'); 
           iter++);

    return iter;
}
```

In the same way a function can be made to skip to the next whitespace character.

```c
char * first_space(char * s) {
    char * iter = s;

    for (; *iter && !(*iter == ' ' || *iter == '\t' || *iter == '\n'); 
           iter++);

    return iter;
}
```

Now counting the words is much simpler. Our for loop doesn't even need a body. It starts with `iter` pointing to the first character of the string, and `count` set to zero. It continues while we haven't run into the null character, and while the first non-space character isn't null.

Each time through we update by getting the first non-space character, and then from that pointer advancing to the first space. This effectively iterates over a "word." At the same time we update count by incrementing it by one.

```c
int main() {
    char * test = "     hello world foo bar      ";
    char * iter;
    int count;

    for (iter = test, count = 0; 
         *iter && *first_nonspace(iter); 
         iter = first_space(first_nonspace(iter)), count++);
    
    printf("Found %d words.\n", count);
}
```

Breaking big problems down into smaller ones is so helpful to understanding what's going on. What I've described is the same logic going on in your program (though I added handling tabs and newlines) but in manageable chunks with more useful names.

Comment: Good advice. Worth an upvote!

Comment: Thanks for the confidence in the advice!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it sure is better to do it this way but I unfortunately had to all that is one function since it's a college exercice and it required so. Nonetheless it really helped me deepen my understanding of the function

Comment: Glad to hear it!